# temporarily store data in electron js localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

i am trying to play a video file in my electron app for the user. but i need the file can't be accessed by user, i searched a bit, tried some codes and found that some guys say things like electron js localstorage are easy to hack and can be accessed by users...
so here are the questions:

1.how can i store a video file locally that can only be played and accessed by electron JS app?

2. is it safe to do this with electron? because i need my app to be cross platform?

Comment: Why can't your user access this video file ? Can you encrypt it ?

Comment: @Nicolas thanks for the comment, i can't let user have the video file but i need it to be there so he/she can play it anytime... can encrypt it yes but if i decrypt the file for playing it must first be stored in hard drive yes? and thats when user can access the file... i dont know if i can decrypt the video and load it in app then encrypt it again?

Comment: Well you can store it on the drive as encrypted, and then when you need it, you get the encrypted version and decrypt it, at this point the file is stored in ram since your didn't rewrite it to disk. You can play it while it's decrypted and then just destroy it once done. If you need it again, just retreive it from the drive and decrypt it again.

Comment: One other way would be to stream it from a server, this way the user never has it on their machine. In my opinion, this is the best way to do but I don't know your context.

Comment: You also can't control the user recording their screen while the video is playing.

Comment: @Nicolas can't let it be on server because my policy is to let user have it offline so he/she wont download and watch it every time, if i decrypt the file is it stored in ram by default? because it is a good thing for me, and crypto js is safe enough to do this?

Comment: @Nicolas yes recording is a big problem....

Comment: I'm not sure about Cryptography in Javascript, That some research you will have to do, As for the store in RAM, your program is run in RAM so as long as you don't rewrite the decrypted data to a file on disk, it will stays in RAM.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you so much for the information Nicolas, you were a great help, now i am trying to use crypto js to encrypt and decrypt the file, hope it works

Comment: I hope it works as well ! I wish you luck !

Comment: @Nicolas can you explain how i can play the video while it is in ram? after decryption? how can i load it into html? or there is other way to play it?

Comment: Basically, when you save data into a variable, it is stored into RAM. at this point, you can use the variable to play your video, i don't know exactly know how to play your video from a variable though.. Once you're done with your video playing, if your destroy de variable, using `delete` for example, the space that was used for your Video will be cleared and it will be deleted from RAM.

Comment: it's a basic concept of computer programming that you don't really have to take care of, since it's taken care of by the language itself.